Passing values from indexed vector into manually-entered labels in ggplot
I would like to pass values from an indexed vector into the expression() function in ggplot. Easiest just to show what I mean. Here is toy data. Three groups each with 11 values.
# Toy data
data.frame(out = c(seq(0,1,.1), seq(0,0.5,.05), seq(0,0.1,.01)),
           time = seq(0,50,5),
           group = factor(rep(letters[1:3],each=11))) -> d

Now create a vector of counts of numbers in each group to pass into legend labels
groupCounts <- table(d$group)

groupCounts

# output
#  a  b  c 
# 11 11 11

Now to manually change legend colours and labels using scale_colour_manual(). I want to pass the number for each group into an expression() function that will render the corresponding label in the legend of the graph, like so
ggplot(data = d,
       mapping = aes(x = time, 
                     y = out,
                     colour = group)) +
  geom_line() +
  scale_colour_manual(labels = c(expression(paste("All (", italic("n"), "=", groupCounts[1], ")")),
                                 expression(paste("0 days (", italic("n"), "=", groupCounts[2], ")")),
                                 expression(paste("1-9 days (", italic("n"), "=", groupCounts[3], ")"))),
                      values = c("#440154",
                                 "#31688E",
                                 "#35B779"))

But the values from the indexed vector do not come out in the graph

When I just manually enter the numbers it works
ggplot(data = d,
       mapping = aes(x = time, 
                     y = out,
                     colour = group)) +
  geom_line() +
  scale_colour_manual(labels = c(expression(paste("All (", italic("n"), "=", 11, ")")),
                                 expression(paste("0 days (", italic("n"), "=", 11, ")")),
                                 expression(paste("1-9 days (", italic("n"), "=", 11, ")"))),
                      values = c("#440154",
                                 "#31688E",
                                 "#35B779"))


So how do I get the indexed vector values to show up as numbers in the legend labels?
Any help much appreciated

You can use bquote() instead of expression():
library(ggplot2)

ggplot(data = d,
       mapping = aes(x = time, 
                     y = out,
                     colour = group)) +
  geom_line() +
  scale_colour_manual(labels = c(bquote(paste("All (", italic("n"), "=", .(groupCounts[1]), ")")),
                                 bquote(paste("0 days (", italic("n"), "=", .(groupCounts[2]), ")")),
                                 bquote(paste("1-9 days (", italic("n"), "=", .(groupCounts[3]), ")"))),
                      values = c("#440154",
                                 "#31688E",
                                 "#35B779"))



Thank you so much @L Tyrone. What does the full stop and parentheses around the indexed vector within bquote() do?

expression() and bquote() create unevaluated expressions, so the outputs are not computed. My understanding is that they are list objects. bquote() is more flexible with .() which allows evaluated values to be passed to an otherwise unevaluated expression. This link gives an explanation of why and how, but that part of R is beyond my understanding. Thankfully, I am not alone and when I encountered this for the first time, this blog post saved the day.

Yes all that programming stuff makes my head hurt, quosures and lazy eval and all that. I appreciate the explanation

One possible solution is to use ggtext and glue
library(glue)
library(ggtext)
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)

data.frame(out = c(seq(0,1,.1), seq(0,0.5,.05), seq(0,0.1,.01)),
           time = seq(0,50,5),
           group = factor(rep(letters[1:3],each=11))) -> d

nice_labs = d |> 
  mutate(counts = n(), 
   nice_labs = case_when(
          group == 'a' ~ glue('All (*n* = {counts})'),
          group == 'b' ~ glue('0 days (*n* = {counts}'),
          group == 'c' ~ glue('1-9 days (*n* = {counts}')),
        .by = group)



ggplot(nice_labs, aes(x = time, y = out, color = nice_labs)) +
  geom_line() +
  scale_color_manual(
                     values = c("#440154",
                                "#31688E",
                                "#35B779")) +
  theme(legend.text = element_markdown())


Created on 2024-09-12 with reprex v2.1.0
